# context.SaveChangesAsync() doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

I have a problem to update my database with EF.
In my application i have Orders and OrderPositions. An OrderPosition can be a FoodPosition or a ReservationPosition. So i have two lists in my Order class one for the FoodPositions and one for the ReservationPositions.

My problem is by updating an Order with its FoodPositions and ReservationPositions.
When i want to save the changes on my Database in this line:

```cs
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This line is part of UpdateAsync method:

```cs
private async Task UpdateAsync(Order order)
{
    Order contextOrder = context.Set<Order>()
        .Include(o => o.FoodPositions)
        .Include(o => o.ReservationPositions)
        .Single(e => e.Id == order.Id);

    contextOrder.FoodPositions = order.FoodPositions;
    contextOrder.ReservationPositions = order.ReservationPositions;
    contextOrder.Status = order.Status;
    contextOrder.Cost = order.Cost;
    contextOrder.CostCenter = order.CostCenter;

    context.Update(contextOrder);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

It doesn't finish the line and goes back to where the method was called.

this is the code in my database context to bind the foreign keys:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<FoodPosition>()
    .HasOne<Order>()
    .WithMany(e => e.FoodPositions);

modelBuilder.Entity<ReservationPosition>()
    .HasOne<Order>()
    .WithMany(e => e.ReservationPositions);
```

When i try to update an Order without these two lines:

```cs
contextOrder.FoodPositions = order.FoodPositions;
contextOrder.ReservationPositions = order.ReservationPositions;
```

it works just fine and it goes through the line with saveChangesAsync.

I don't get any Errors, it just doesn't work the way i want it. Because it doesn't save the updated order as expected with all the updated property values and the new OrderPositions.

Maybe there are some conflicts by replacing the OrderPositions with new ones and it doesn't know how to deal with it in the database.

Comment: What exception do you have if you put your code in a try/catch bloc ?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't finish the line"? Whenever using async methods you should make sure each task is awaited, that a task is returned from all async methods. If you cannot return the task, due to being in a button event handler for example, you need to make sure to catch and handle any exceptions from the `await`.

Comment: This is the exception i get:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'FoodPosition' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.' @MarcelCallo

Comment: @Flu the bug is caused by the misuse of EF Core. SaveChanges works fine. `UpdateAsync` is fundamentally broken though and suggests you're using a CRUD class over DbContext. That's a very bad anti-pattern, DbContext is a high-level Unit of Work, not a low level CRUD class. `contextOrder` is *already* tracked in the `Modified` state. When you call `context.Update` on it, you try to *attach* it and all related objects in the `Added` or `Modified` state.

Comment: Where does the `order` parameter value come from? If it was loaded from the database, you don't need `UpdateAsync` at all. If it came from an ASP.NET Core requesty, `contect.Update(order)` is enough to track it as modified. `Update` is essentially an UPSERT. It attaches an object and its relations in the `Added` state if their PKs have default values or the `Modified` state if they have actual values. Given that the query returned `contextOrder`, `ID` clearly has a non-default value

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the exception message. And when you're there anyway, please also fix capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation about [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/)

> Entity instances become tracked when they are:
>
> - Returned from a query executed against the database
> - Explicitly attached to the DbContext by Add, Attach, Update, or similar methods
> - Detected as new entities connected to existing tracked entities

So, when your initial query returns the contextOrder, `contextOrder.FoodPositions` is tracked, but `order.FoodPositions` is not tracked. Both of these objects presumably share the same Id, So when you run `.Update` it has two different tracked objects with the same Id, i.e. what the exception says. This has nothing to do with being asynchronous or not.

You could try adding [`.AsNoTracking()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) to ensure entities are not tracked until you do that explicitly, but note that when you do `.Update(..)`, a search will be done on the object graph, and all found entities with existing keys will be tracked as "modified", while entities without keys (i.e. 0) will be tracked as "added".

You can also do `contextOrder.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Modified` to set the tracking state of an single entity explicitly.

You might also need to consider the lifetime of your context object. The approach I'm most familiar with ensures that the context is short lived. I.e. you create your context, uses it for whatever you need to do, and dispose it. If your context is long lived you need pay closer attention to what entities are tracked or not, and in what state.

Answer (score 0):

After you've get the entity by it's Id from the database and made changes to the entity, you can simply call context.SaveChangesAsync() method of the DbContext to propagate the changes to the database.

```
private async Task UpdateAsync(Order order)
{
    // ...
    contextOrder.Cost = order.Cost;
    contextOrder.CostCenter = order.CostCenter;

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating detached aggregate entities requires special care. In EF, references are everything, and if the DbContext is not tracking the reference you are giving it, you are going to encounter exceptions or duplicate data situations. If it's already tracking another reference for the same row, again, an exception.

Firstly, when loading a tracked reference (existingOrder) you do not use `Update`. `Update` is used to attach a detached entity and tell EF to treat the entire thing as modified. This doesn't apply to other entities referenced, so those would need to be done individually. I don't recommend using `Update` as it is inefficient, marking everything as changed even if nothing actually changed, and you're "trusting" the data coming in, so there are many situations (like web applications) where that is exposing your system to tampering. Instead, load the tracked entity, copy allowed values across, then call `SaveChanges()`.

The next issue is dealing with navigation properties, your FoodPositions and ReservationPositions. With navigation properties you need to consider whether these represent associations or a more "owned" type relationship. For instance are these a many-to-many relationship where an Order associates to one or more existing Food or FoodPositions, or are FoodPositions created and treated as a one-to-many children of the order? The same basic rules apply in both cases, but they will be handled slightly differently as anything associated needs to be tracked by the DbContext before we save the Order.

The typical code structure I recommend for updating associations looks something like this: (Applying code for FoodPositions, you can apply it to ReservationPositions. This assumes a more owned one-to-many relationship)

```
private async Task UpdateAsync(Order order)
{
    Order contextOrder = await context.Set<Order>()
        .Include(o => o.FoodPositions)
        .Include(o => o.ReservationPositions)
        .SingleAsync(e => e.Id == order.Id);

    var existingFoodPositionIds = contextOrder.FoodPositions
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .ToList();
    var updatedFoodPositionIds = order.FoodPositions
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .ToList();
    var foodPositionIdsToAdd = updatedFoodPositionIds
        .Except(existingFoodPositionIds);
    var foodPositionIdsToRemove = existingFoodPositionIds
        .Except(updatedFoodPositionIds);

    if (foodPositionIdsToRemove.Any())
    {
        var foodPositionsToRemove = contextOrder.FoodPositions
            .Where(x => foodPositionIdsToRemove.Contains(x.Id))
            .ToList();
        foreach(var foodPosition in foodPositionsToRemove)
            contextOrder.FoodPositions.Remove(foodPosition);
    }
    if (foodPositionIdsToAdd.Any())
    {
        var foodPositionsToAdd = order.FoodPositions
            .Where(x => foodPositionIdsToAdd.Contains(x.Id))
            .ToList();
        foreach(var foodPosition in foodPositionsToAdd)
            contextOrder.FoodPositions.Add(foodPosition);
    }

    contextOrder.Status = order.Status;
    contextOrder.Cost = order.Cost;
    contextOrder.CostCenter = order.CostCenter;

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Essentially we compare the lists to find what items need to be added or removed, then proceed to add or remove them to the tracked order. This can involve a fair bit of code, so it's something I would likely break off into a simple method to call (i.e. updateOrderFoodPositions(order, contextOrder)) rather than growing the UpdateOrder to cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to care about navigation collections by yourself, they are not updated automatically when they are detached.

I have created universal method `MergeCollections` which may help you to simplify this case. Using this method you can update collection properties.

```cs
private async Task UpdateAsync(Order order)
{
    Order contextOrder = context.Set<Order>()
        .Include(o => o.FoodPositions)
        .Include(o => o.ReservationPositions)
        .Single(e => e.Id == order.Id);

    CollectionHelpers.MergeCollections(context, contextOrder.FoodPositions, order.FoodPositions, e => e.Id);
    CollectionHelpers.MergeCollections(context, contextOrder.ReservationPositions, order.ReservationPositions, e => e.Id);

    contextOrder.Status = order.Status;
    contextOrder.Cost = order.Cost;
    contextOrder.CostCenter = order.CostCenter;

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And implementation:

```cs
public class CollectionHelpers
{
    public static void MergeCollections<TItem, TKey>(
        DbContext context,
        ICollection<TItem> destination,
        ICollection<TItem> source,
        Func<TItem, TKey> keyFunc) 
        where TItem: notnull
        where TKey : notnull
    {
        MergeCollections(destination, source, keyFunc, keyFunc, e => e,
            (d, s) => context.Entry(d).CurrentValues.SetValues(s),
            d => context.Remove(d)
        );
    }

    public static void MergeCollections<TItem, TKey>(
        ICollection<TItem> destination,
        ICollection<TItem> source,
        Func<TItem, TKey> keyFunc,
        Action<TItem, TItem> onUpdate,
        Action<TItem> onDelete) 
        where TKey : notnull
    {
        MergeCollections(destination, source, keyFunc, keyFunc, e => e, onUpdate, onDelete);
    }

    public static void MergeCollections<TDestination, TSource, TDestinationKey>(
        ICollection<TDestination> destination,
        ICollection<TSource> source,
        Func<TDestination, TDestinationKey> destinationKeyFunc,
        Func<TSource, TDestinationKey> sourceKeyFunc,
        Func<TSource, TDestination> insertFactory,
        Action<TDestination, TSource> onUpdate,
        Action<TDestination> onDelete) 
        where TDestinationKey : notnull
    {
        // shortcuts
        if (source.Count == 0)
        {
            while (destination.Count > 0)
            {
                var first = destination.First();
                destination.Remove(first);
                onDelete(first);
            }   
            return;
        }

        if (destination.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach(var s in source)
                destination.Add(insertFactory(s));
            return;
        }

        var sourceDic = source.ToDictionary(sourceKeyFunc);

        foreach (var d in destination.ToList())
        {
            var key = destinationKeyFunc(d);
            if (sourceDic.TryGetValue(key, out var foundSource))
            {
                onUpdate(d, foundSource);
                sourceDic.Remove(key);
            }
            else
            {
                destination.Remove(d);
                onDelete(d);
            }
        }

        if (sourceDic.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(var s in sourceDic.Values)
                destination.Add(insertFactory(s));
        }
    }
}
```