# Update parent with children

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an object, parent, which contains nested objects (children). I receive a new parent object with new/different/updated children from the frontend. How can I best update these?

My idea is something like

```cs
// Assume parentEntity is the updated object from the frontend
foreach (var newChild in parentEntity.ChildEntities)
{
    // Check if the entity already exists in the parent entity's collection
    var existingChildEntity = parentEntity.ChildEntities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == newChild.Id);

    if (existingChildEntity != null)
    {
        // Update the existing entity
        _dbContext.Entry(existingChildEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(newChild);
    }
    else
    {
        // Add the new entity
        parentEntity.ChildEntities.Add(newChild);
    }
}

// Remove child entities that are no longer present in the updated object
foreach (var existingChildEntity in parentEntity.ChildEntities.ToList())
{
    if (!parentEntity.ChildEntities.Any(e => e.Id == existingChildEntity.Id))
    {
        parentEntity.ChildEntities.Remove(existingChildEntity);
    }
}

// Save changes to the database
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Another approach could be: I load the entity and its children using eager loading (Include). Then, I set the children to null and iterate over the newChildren, creating new child entities for them. I essentially delete the old records and recreate all of them anew. But I don't like this approach.

Do you have ideas and suggestions for improvement?

Comment: If you use `Automapper`, you can use [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/Automapper.Collection). Or reuse my function [MergeCollections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77506930/10646316), which is analogue of your "another" approach, which is more performant.