Updating post with many-to-many relationship with Entity Framework Core
I have following entities -
BaseEntity for keys:
/// <summary>
/// Base entity
/// </summary>
[Index("Uid", IsUnique = true)]
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Guid Uid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

Post:
public class Post : BaseEntity
{
    [MaxLength(100), MinLength(5)]
    public required string Title { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(3000), MinLength(50)]
    public required string Text { get; set; }
    public required DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public required bool IsAnonymous { get; set; } = false;

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public PostCount PostCount { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<Comment>? Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }
}

Topic:
public class Topic : BaseEntity
{
    public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

Their configuration:
public static void ConfigureTopics(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Topic>().ToTable("Topics");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Topic>().Property(x => x.Type).IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Topic>().HasMany(x => x.Posts)
        .WithMany(x => x.Topics)
        .UsingEntity(t => t.ToTable("PostsTopics"));
}

Here is the method to create a post that works fine:
public async Task<PostModel> Create(CreatePostModel model, Guid userId)
{
    try
    {
        await _createValidator.CheckAsync(model);

        await using var context = await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
    
        // Create a new Post entity
        var post = _mapper.Map<Post>(model);

        if (post.Date.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
            post.Date = post.Date.ToUniversalTime();

        // Create a new PostCount entity
        var postCount = new PostCount
        {
            Post = post
        };

        // Associate the Post and PostCount entities
        post.PostCount = postCount;

        post.UserId = userId;

        // Fetch existing topics by Uid
        post.Topics = await context.Topics
            .Where(t => model.Topics.Contains(t.Uid))
            .ToListAsync();
    
        context.AttachRange(post.Topics);
    
        // Add the entities to the context
        await context.Posts.AddAsync(post);
        await context.PostCounts.AddAsync(postCount);

        // Save changes to the database
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        post.User = await context.Users.FirstAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
    
        var createdPost = _mapper.Map<PostModel>(post);
    
        return createdPost;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error($"Error creating post. Error message: {e.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}

PostsTopics table in the database:
-- auto-generated definition
create table "PostsTopics"
(
    "PostsId"  integer not null
        constraint "FK_PostsTopics_Posts_PostsId"
            references "Posts"
            on delete cascade,
    "TopicsId" integer not null
        constraint "FK_PostsTopics_Topics_TopicsId"
            references "Topics"
            on delete cascade,
    constraint "PK_PostsTopics"
        primary key ("PostsId", "TopicsId")
);

alter table "PostsTopics"
    owner to postgres;

create index "IX_PostsTopics_TopicsId"
    on "PostsTopics" ("TopicsId");

Here is the update method. The problem here is EF Core for some reason is not removing topics from PostTopics table, and that is why I am getting an error

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
welisten_api-1         |  ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_PostsTopics"

When I try to pass empty list of topics, it updates every other property, and saves them, but the topics remain as before:
public async Task Update(Guid id, Guid userId, UpdatePostModel model)
{
    try
    {
        await _updateValidator.CheckAsync(model);

        await using var context = await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();

        var post = await context.Posts
            .Include(x => x.User)
            .Include(x => x.PostCount)
            .Include(x => x.Topics)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Uid == id);

        if (post == null)
            throw new ProcessException($"Post with ID: {id} not found");

        if (post.UserId != userId)
            throw new AuthenticationException("Authentication failed");

        context.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
        
        // Clear existing topics
        post.Topics.Clear();

        // Update other properties of the post
        post.Title = model.Title;
        post.Text = model.Text;
        post.IsAnonymous = model.IsAnonymous;
        
        // Update topics
        post.Topics = await context.Topics
            .Where(t => model.Topics.Contains(t.Uid))
            .ToListAsync();
        
        context.AttachRange(post.Topics);
        
        // Save changes again to update the many-to-many relationship
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error($"Error updating post with ID: {id}. Error message: {e.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}

I tried to first clear the topics with Post.Topics.Clear(), save them. Then assign new topics and save the changes once more, but it did not help either

What property is being used for Primary Key?  Your classes does not contain a Key.  When you have a key you can only have one item with any key value.  Because you do not have a key your database has duplicates.  You first need to remove the duplicates , create a key, and then do a migration so mapping gets updated.

@jdweng, updated the post. I have "BaseEntity" with keys, which is inherited for other entities. the problem is not with the keys

Error says "Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_PostsTopics"  The issue is with Keys.

Are you getting Id and Uid mixed up? .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Uid == id);

@jdweng, I meant that the problem is not with having no keys as you commented earlier

@jdweng, no, I am not getting the ids mixed up. "When I try to pass empty list of topics, it updates every other property, and saves them, but the topics remain as before"

Are you saying topics is always empty? I'm confused because you say you are getting an error "duplicate key".  When the error occurs I wouldn't expect the database to get updated.  So I still think you are trying to add a duplicate key.  Are you getting error when you reach SaveChangesAsync() or someplace else?  I need to determine if the error is occurring in the context or the database.  Did you perform a Migration?  The mapping between the context classes and the Database may not be in sync.

@jdweng. Yes I did perfom the migration. Please read the post again. 1) The create method is working fine, it creates everything right, including topics (checked in db).  2) However, when I am trying to update the post, ef core tries to the same topics again in the PostsTopics table, instead of removing old records, and replacing with new ones. 3) The reason why Update is working, when I pass empty list with Topics, is because no more topics is being added (in this case it should remove all topics related to this post, but it just leaves the topics as they are)

Are you getting the error "duplicate id"?  I would think if you are getting the error the database is not updating.  So error has to be fixed before update will work.  I linq the "q" is for query.  So it is only used for reading (not writing).  The Create method doesn't use linq so it works.  The update method changes the row POST only (firstordefault).   What does Post return?  Put break point an make sure it is return good results.  I do not think you need "context.AttachRange(post.Topics);"  This is creating the duplicate.  The SaveChangesAsync() will then update database.

Post is a link to the existing row of the database.  Using AttachRange is adding the row a second time and giving an error (creating a duplicate key).  AttachRange should only be used if the row doesn't exist.

@jdweng, "AttachRange()" in create method was needed to prevent ef try to recreate same topics in Topics table, without it, there was the error with duplicated Ids, but in Topics table, which is why I included it in update method as well

You need to do a query to first determine if the ID already exists in database which is the variable "post".  I do not think it will return a null.  Instead you have to use count property to determine if it exists "if (post.Count > 0)".  Only do context.AttachRange when the ID does not exist.

You cannot update relationships by doing a Clear then populating the list with the current IDs, as EF will complain about items that weren't meant to be removed (cleared then re-added) Instead, look at the example in my answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77502406/context-savechangesasync-doesnt-work-as-expected/77505148#77505148) for how to update collection references to add and remove items as needed.

@jdweng thank you that you tried to understand the problem and help me, however I managed to find the cause of the problem and its fix yesterday. I shared my solution in answers if you want to check

Not sure why you are deleting and then adding.  You should be able to modify an existing item without doing post.Topics.Add(topic);.  When an item does not exist use post.Topics.Add(topic);

So, after trial and error I made it working. The problem was in attaching post.Topics context.AttachRange(post.Topics); before changing them. However, the EF started complaining that it cannot track two entities at the same time, when I tried to update the values in post.Topics with
// Update topics
post.Topics = await context.Topics
  .Where(t => model.Topics.Contains(t.Uid))
  .ToListAsync()

I had to manually check which topics should be removed and whic ones to be added.
Here is final working solution for my problem:
public async Task Update(Guid id, Guid userId, UpdatePostModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            await _updateValidator.CheckAsync(model);

            await using var context = await _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();

            var post = await context.Posts
                .Include(x => x.User)
                .Include(x => x.PostCount)
                .Include(x => x.Topics)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Uid == id);

            if (post == null)
                throw new ProcessException($"Post with ID: {id} not found");

            if (post.UserId != userId)
                throw new AuthenticationException("Authentication failed");

            context.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.AttachRange(post.Topics);

            // Update other properties of the post
            post.Title = model.Title;
            post.Text = model.Text;
            post.IsAnonymous = model.IsAnonymous;

            // Update topics
            var existingTopicIds = post.Topics.Select(t => t.Uid).ToList();
            var newTopicIds = model.Topics;

            // Remove topics that are not in the new list
            foreach (var topic in post.Topics.ToList())
            {
                if (!newTopicIds.Contains(topic.Uid))
                {
                    post.Topics.Remove(topic);
                }
            }
            
            // Add new topics
            foreach (var topicId in newTopicIds)
            {
                if (!existingTopicIds.Contains(topicId))
                {
                    var topic = await context.Topics.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Uid == topicId);
                    if (topic != null)
                    {
                        post.Topics.Add(topic);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Save changes to update the post entity
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error($"Error updating post with ID: {id}. Error message: {e.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

